# Scikit-Image gives me this error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py", line 53, in pil_to_ndarray
    im.getdata()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1165, in getdata
    self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 212, in load
    s = read(self.decodermaxblock)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Custom vgg2.py", line 154, in <module>
    img = io.imread(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_io.py", line 61, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 211, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py", line 37, in imread
    return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py", line 61, in pil_to_ndarray
    raise ValueError(error_message)
ValueError: Could not load "" 
Reason: "[Errno 5] Input/output error"
Please see documentation at: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries
```

Comment: `ValueError: Could not load ""` occurred because `file_path` is an empty string. The error is saying that it failed to load a file called `""`.

Comment: I have checked that. The same code runs on kaggle but not on my machine.